# Difference between predicted and plotted lm regression line with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I want to display a bivariate linear regression line in a **ggplot2** `geom_jitter` plot. Q49, the outcome, is a 1-10 interval variable and Q262, the predictor, is age in years. My `lm` model is

```
lm_model <- lm(Q49 ~ Q262, na.action = na.omit)
```

Which gives me the following estimates and confidence intervals:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 6.573616   0.119286  55.108  < 2e-16 ***
      Q262  0.018909   0.002544   7.432 1.39e-13 ***

                 2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept) 6.33972601 6.80750682
      Q262  0.01392002 0.02389794
```

When I plot the two variables in `ggplot`

```
ggplot(df, aes(Q262, Q49)) + geom_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0.2, color = "black") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10, 1))
```

I get this:

[image: Plotted regression line]

The model predicts my intercept to be 6.573616 (6.33972601 - 6.80750682). However, the plotted regression line puts the intercept somewhere at 6.8, which is at the upper limit of the confidence interval.

Why is that and how can I draw the exact regression line my model predicts into the plot? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The lower limit in your plot is approx Q262=18, not Q262=0. If you `+expand_limits(x=0)` and add `fullrange=TRUE` to your `geom_smooth` call that might clarify things ...

Comment: Thanks. I tried the fullrange option before (should have said that) but not the "expand_limits". Where would the latter go to?

Comment: The plot is deceptive because it doesn't show the y-intercept (when x is 0). You can also use `fullrange=TRUE` and add `+ xlim(0,NA)` to the ggplot. Judging by the slope of the line, I think the line reaches around 6.6 at Q262 = 0.

Comment: Forget that. I figured it out. Indeed, now the intercept is correctly displayed in the plot. @BenBolker

Comment: @LC-datascientist Thanks. Your solution produces the same plot.

Comment: I recoded the age var so that it begins at 0. Then the plot and the model converge, and the plot looks normal. 
 
Thanks for your help!